# Using Spring security 6 custom CSRF filter is not being invoked

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-config

I am migrating from Spring security 5.1.4 to 6.1.0. In the documentation of Spring security I find that the behaviour of adding the csrf token on all requests have changed.  But you may specifically configure Spring to add a CSRF token to all requests (including the GET):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.2-SNAPSHOT/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#deferred-csrf-token

I am trying to make a configuration, ( I am not using Spring boot, it a legacy application)  to always add the CSRF token to all HTTP requests including the GET.
And I also like to call a custom filter to be able to do more using the csrf token on the request.

Below I listed my configuration, however using the following configuration I am not able to invoke my custom filter. Also Spring CsrfFilter is never invoked.
Could you please help me finding out why the CSRF filter or the custom filter are never invoked?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static String CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "MyCSRFToken";

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        // set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
        requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);
        http
            .addFilterBefore(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/","GET"))
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler));


        return http.build();
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        final HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName(CSRF_HEADER_NAME);
        repository.setParameterName(CSRF_HEADER_NAME);
        return repository;
    }


    static class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                        final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            final CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                    .getName());
            System.out.println("Token="+ csrf.getToken());
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't see any suggestions, However for the ones who run into the same problem, I found my solution. In my own mis-configuration.
For some reason my filter config was not there any more. 
Please in your web.xml (in case you are using xml config) you will have to see 
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
Then it works as expected